# Hibernate Pojo Design for Contact List

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design

I want to implement database for set of users and contact list of each user.
For this I was thinking instead of creating database tables,want to create
Hibernate Pojo.

first i thought:

```
class User{

  BigDecimal Id;
   //Contact List
  Set<User> contacts
}
```

but above will create data redundancy;

So I thought,to create user as Master Table
And a another class Contact

```
class User{
String userName;
BigDecimal userId;
@OneToOne;
Contact contact;
}

class Contact{
@OneToOne
User user;
@?;   
Set<User> users;
}
```

but i can not figure out How set of users of Contact should be mapped User class.

Kindly any one suggest what should be design approach.

Answer (score 1):

User & Contact table will be in a one to many relationship. 
One User can have many contacts.

```
class User{
String userName;
BigDecimal userId;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
Set<Contact> contacts;
}

class Contact{
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")    
User user;
}
```

USER_ID will be a primary key in User table & a foreign key in Contact table.

Check out this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) for an example

Comment: If we go this way, in User table,there will be two columns user_id,user_name and Contact table will have one column user_id(fk),it will not show any user-user associations, So we need two columns in Contact table and again i do not know,how another User of Contact  class will be associated with User class.

Comment: What do you mean by user-user association? Read the example in the link you'll get an understanding how one to many mapping is done. I think you are confusing yourself.

Comment: I know how One to Many Mapping is done,but in this case one to Many mapping is with same class, let me give you an example, in User table we have  {user_id,user_name}:{1,'a_name': 2,'b_name': 3,'c_name'} data and suppose i want user_id 2,3 is in contact list of user_id 1, in above design, Contact table will have just used_id:{2,3} entry, this is not going to say user_id 2,3 is in contact list of user_id 1.